# How to pass array through jquery get function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

let's assume I have controller method like this

```
public ActionResult GetSelected(int[] ids)
{
   //do something
   return Json (ids, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

and in view file I have function which creates array named list. 
How can I pass my array to controller using $.get function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this :

```
   var data = { 1, 2 };
    $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action('GetSelected','ControllerName')',
    data: {
      getSelected : data
      },
       success:function(data){
      //Do Something With the return data or HttpStatusCode
      }
    });
```

Comment: Make sure that your Action is either [HttpGet] or [HttpPost].